# Understanding 2-sided p-values in a binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution

I had a questions about ***2-sided p-values*** in a ***binomial distribution:***

Given the symmetric shape of a binomial dist. when $p = 0.5$, why the below observations (i.e., **2** and **13**) which have exact opposite positions in such a binomial dist. don't have the same probability. **In R**, this inequality is shown as follows:

```
pbinom( 2, 15, prob = .5) # 0.00369

pbinom(13, 15, prob = .5, lower.tail = F) # 0.000488
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, this is an off-by-one error. From the documentation:

> lower.tail
> logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].

so:

> pbinom( 2, 15, prob = .5) # 0.00369 =P[X ≤ 2]
>
> pbinom(13, 15, prob = .5, lower.tail = F) # 0.000488 = P[X > 13]

Comment: Thanks, you mean in reality P[X >= 13] is equal to P[X <= 2] ?  Is this off-by-one error only true in the case binomial dist. or for all symmetric dist. in R?    What are your thoughts regarding the second question?

Comment: Indeed p(x>=13)=p(x>12) is p(x<=2). The off by one error is not due to the symmetry but because the bionomial distribution is a discrete distribution rather than continuous. Therefore p(x<=2) = p(x=2)+p(x=1)+p(x=0) but p(x>13)= p(x=14)+p(x=15). These differences between strict and weak inequality don't occur for continuous distributions where including or excluding the boundary makes only a nominal difference.